# ENOENT: no such file or directory, at Object.fs.mkdirSync

Tags: node.js, express

I'm currently starting up my NodeJS application and I want to check if folder exist action:

```
[Node] log/20190405 ----------created the folder log/20190405/2019040500.log-----------------
[Node] fs.js:885
[Node]   return binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path),
[Node]                  ^
[Node] 
[Node] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'log/20190405'
[Node]     at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
[Node]     at fs_1.default.access (/home/lordrauf/Documents/myproject/dist/util/logger.js:25:30)
[Node]     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
```

The weird thing, I'm not sure where the folder is located, but the check fails on the following snippet:

```
function checkFilePromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.access(`log/${format("yyyyMMdd", new Date())}`, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
            console.log(`log/${format("yyyyMMdd", new Date())} ${err ? `----------created the folder ${logName}-----------------` : '----------log folder exists----------'}`);
            if (err) {
                fs.mkdirSync(`log/${format("yyyyMMdd", new Date())}`);
                console.log(err)
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(true)
            }
        });
    })
}
```

If someone know how to solve this issue, please help me. Any advise appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: to check if folder exists use [fs.stats](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) and also use Promise.promisifyAll(fs) rather wrapping each method.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the view, but could you show me the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `resursive` option to create the directories:

```js
function checkFilePromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.access(`log/${format("yyyyMMdd", new Date())}`, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
            console.log(`log/${format("yyyyMMdd", new Date())} ${err ? `----------created the folder ${logName}-----------------` : '----------log folder exists----------'}`);
            if (err) {

// Use `resursive` option
                fs.mkdirSync(`log/${format("yyyyMMdd", new Date())}`, {recursive: true});

                console.log(err)
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(true)
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: You've made a  typo in "recursive" property in options. I've tried to edit it, but I have to make at least 6 chars change.

Comment: Hi @KrzysztofCzereczon thanks for pointing out, I've fixed it.